# How to use interceptors in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, interceptor, angular-dart, angular-http-interceptors

I have a `AngularJS` app with this simple `http-interceptor`:

```
'use strict';
app.factory('myInterceptorService', ['$q','$location', function ($q,$location) {

    var myInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

    var _request = function (config) {
        // some code
    }

    var _responseError = function (rejection) {
        // some code
    }

    myInterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
    myInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;

    return myInterceptorServiceFactory;
}]);
```

And I register the interceptor like this:

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptorService');
});
```

But, I couldn't any way to do this in `AngularDart`. Have any suggestion please?

Comment: There is nothing like interceptors in Dart. You can wrap the HTTP client in a custom class where you add custom behavior

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648034/how-to-log-http-requests-in-flutter

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer. I did wrap the client as you mentioned in your first comment.